# Is there a way to Work on Oracle\Scott account Online?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database  homework the must be done on Scott account , is there a way to get the schema ? 
And where i can find an online sql editor that supports Oracle ?

Comment: [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) and choose Oracle.

The ddl for schema can be found easily on the internet.

Comment: @FlorinGhita i was just working on it before posting this question 
however it gave me an error when i fed it with the Scott schema , thats why i asked for the schema again 

this is the error message

Schema Creation Failed: access denied to execute "Grant" SQL statment for datasource 4_0fdd6:

this is where i got the schema from 

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10653227

Comment: SQLFiddle (sensibly) probably doesn't give you DBA rights which are necessary for the create user / grant statements. Instead of creating the SCOTT user, just perform the CREATE and INSERT statements. This will create them in whatever schema SQLFiddle assigns to you.

Comment: It worked !!! thanks . Please put it as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: It originally was @FlorinGhita's answer, so he should do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) and choose Oracle. 
The ddl for schema can be found easily on the internet.
Just run the create and insert statements and you can run queries on right panel.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend installing the [Oracle Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/index.html) - just check the "install demo database" (or similar) option during installation, and you're ready to go.

The installation package also contains *SQL Developer*, which is a pretty decent SQL editor.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer , however im afraid my internet connection wont help me ,that's why i asked for online editor .